# What should be iterator_category for a stashing iterator?

Tags: c++, iterator

#### Context:

I am trying to build a container that will behave as a wrapper around a multi-dimensional array of run time defined dimensions - in fact the underlying array is of course a 1D array of the total size. The main part is that `operator []` returns a wrapper on the sub array.

As containers need iterators, I am currently implementing iterators on that container, both `Container::iterator` and `Container::const_iterator`. I try hard to mimic standard container iterators, and my implementation respects almost all requirements for a random access iterator except for:

> Forward iterators [forward.iterators]
>
> ...
> <sup>6</sup> If `a` and `b` are both dereferenceable, then `a == b` if and only if `*a` and `*b` are bound to the same object.

The reason for not respecting it, is that `operator *` has to return a reference to a sub-container. So my implementation is a *stashing iterator* that contains a sub-container member that moves with the iterator, and `operator *` returns a reference to this member object

Over simplified implementation:

```
template <class T>
class SubArray {
    T *arr;
    size_t *sizes;
    size rowsize;
public:
    ...
    Iterator<T> begin() {
        return Iterator<T>(operator[](0));
    }
    ...
};

class Iterator<T> {
   SubArray elt;
public:
    Iterator(const SubArray<T>& pos): elt(pos) {}
    ...
    SubArray<T>& operator *() {
        return elt;
    ...
};
```

According to cppreference (and to source of different implementations) `std::filesystem::path::iterator` is also a stashing iterator.

#### Question

The `iterator_category` member of an iterator is supposed to help other classes to identify the type of an iterator from input iterator to random access. What should be the `iterator_category` of my stashing iterator, that fulfills almost all requirements for a random access iterator but fails for one point of forward iterator? Note: this is enough to make `std::reverse_iterator` not usable on it.

Remark:

I can confirm that `std::filesystem::path::iterator` contains for Clang implementation:

```
typedef bidirectional_iterator_tag iterator_category;
```

but also a marker to prevent `std::reverve_iterator` to try to use it

#### References:

- full source for my container class on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/196628/146901)
- question about `std::reverse_iterator` on a stashing container on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28595084/3545273)
- `std::reverse_iterator` on [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/reverse_iterator) (see the note above the example code)

Comment: If the iterator doesn't meet the requirements to be a forward iterator, then it is, at most, an input iterator or an output iterator.

Comment: Why do you have to return a reference to the sub array?  Can't you just return a reference to the element the iterator points to?

Comment: Wait... what happens if you try and modify `*it`? `auto arr = SubArray<int>{/*2D array*/}; auto subarr = SubArray<int>{/*1D array*/}; auto it = arr.begin(); *it = subarr;`

Comment: @YSC: I have never tested that! The default assignment operator for `SubArray` should replace `it.elt`, making `it` point to `subarr`. I think that I shall have to document this, at least as *don't* or *beware*...

Comment: I'm not sure whether it is a bug of libc++. libstdc++ indeed [implements std::filesystem::path::iterator as a forward iterator](https://wandbox.org/permlink/7KTECZ2YbbYXDLVk), so it is reasonable to define its category as  `bidirectional_iterator_tag`. However, libc++ [does not implement it as a forward iterator](https://wandbox.org/permlink/2QOFVyyyRTPE9o3C).