# No reverse iterators for `std::filesystem::path`?

Tags: c++, std-filesystem, reverse-iterator

Is there a technical reason why `std::filesystem::path` doesn't offer reverse iterators (i.e., `rbegin` and `rend`)?

If I have a `std::filesystem::path` for `/a/b/c/b/d/b/e` and I want to find the first component that matches `b`, I can use `std::find(p.begin(), p.end(), fs::path("b"))`.

But if I want to find the *last* component that matches `b`, I can't just switch to reverse iterators.  I can write my own loop, but it seems like this would be a common operation that would have been "almost free" to implement.

Is there something about the design of the interface that would make it difficult to provide reverse iterators?

Comment: From [this page of cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/reverse_iterator#Notes): "*std::reverse_iterator does not work with iterators whose dereference returns a reference to a member of *this (so-called "stashing iterators"). An example of a stashing iterator is std::filesystem::path::iterator.*"

Comment: @Ruks:  That explains it.  Thanks!  (If you convert that comment to an answer, I'll award the apoints.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this page of cppreference.com:

> "std::reverse_iterator does not work with iterators whose dereference returns a reference to a member of *this (so-called "stashing iterators"). An example of a stashing iterator is std::filesystem::path::iterator."

Also from a page of boost.org, which says:

> Path iterators store their value objects internally and when dereferenced return references to those internal objects. They cannot be used with iterator adaptors such as std::reverse_iterator that assume references obtained by dereferencing an iterator point to objects that out-live the iterator itself.

To find a more detailed explanation on stashing iterators, visit [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51046897/what-could-be-a-least-bad-implementation-for-an-iterator-over-a-proxied-contai).